# Are regular fare ZSSK train tickets valid on any train?

Tags: trains, slovakia

I'm looking to travel by train from Bratislava to Liptovský Mikuláš - I have a flight into Bratislava earlier that day so would prefer to keep my onward options flexible to account for delays while also not arriving late in the evening if it is possible. Looking on the ZSSK website there only seems to be one type of ticket labeled as "regular fare" - but also "basic fare"?

[image: Screenshot of ZSSK website showing a train from Bratislava to Liptovský Mikuláš]

I've noticed that this price seems to be the same for all trains - including those departing later that day. I also understand from https://www.zssk.sk/en/prices-and-discounts/tickets/ that ZSSK seem to price its tickets on a per km basis.

Does does that mean the ticket is valid on any train that day? Or is it fixed only to the one that I have a reservation for? If I pay a supplement for large items of luggage would that also transfer to a different train?

I have emailed ZSSK but have not had a response, and when phoning received someone who did not speak English.

Comment: IMO, "regular fare" vs. "basic fare" is just an inconsistent translation, nothing to worry about.

Comment: Moreover, don't worry about paying for oversized luggage. In all likelihood, no one will care. Not speaking Slovak works in your favor, since the staff wouldn't want to argue with you. If you get super bad luck and someone really requests an extra surcharge from you, you can just pay a few more cents on board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**For Regular fare (does not apply for free tickets for students etc.)**

If you buy a ticket on website, it is valid for train stated on the ticket and for all **later** trains in that day, except IC trains. This **does not apply** for place reservation and luggage supplement, which are valid only for the first train. **You will need to buy reservations again** if you use next train, see image.

[image: How to buy reservation only when I have a ticket already.]

Source: Could not find any on the website, looked at my own ticket for Ex train. Conditions are stated on the final ticket in .pdf.

Comment: Nice answer, just adding a few more information: if your ticket costs more than €10, you will be offered a free seat reservation (that will be tied to a specific train, of course). Again, this does not apply to IC trains.